# Reset Cumulative sum base on condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a data frame like:

```
customer spend hurdle 
A         20    50      
A         31    50      
A         20    50      
B         50    100     
B         51    100    
B         30    100
```

I want to calculate additional column for Cumulative which will reset base on the same customer when the Cumulative sum greater or equal to the hurdle like following :

```
customer spend hurdle Cumulative 
A         20    50      20
A         31    50      51
A         20    50      20
B         50    100     50
B         51    100    101
B         30    100     30
```

I used the `cumsum` and `groupby` in pandas to but I do not know how to reset it base on the condition.

Following are the code I am currently using:

```
df1['cum_sum'] = df1.groupby(['customer'])['spend'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

which I know it is just a normal cumulative sum. I very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 6):

There could be faster, efficient way. Here's one inefficient `apply` way to do would be.

```
In [3270]: def custcum(x):
      ...:     total = 0
      ...:     for i, v in x.iterrows():
      ...:         total += v.spend
      ...:         x.loc[i, 'cum'] = total
      ...:         if total >= v.hurdle:
      ...:            total = 0
      ...:     return x
      ...:

In [3271]: df.groupby('customer').apply(custcum)
Out[3271]:
  customer  spend  hurdle    cum
0        A     20      50   20.0
1        A     31      50   51.0
2        A     20      50   20.0
3        B     50     100   50.0
4        B     51     100  101.0
5        B     30     100   30.0
```

You may consider using `cython` or `numba` to speed up the `custcum`

---

[Update]

Improved version of [Ido s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784560/2137255) answer.

```
In [3276]: s = df.groupby('customer').spend.cumsum()

In [3277]: np.where(s > df.hurdle.shift(-1), s, df.spend)
Out[3277]: array([ 20,  51,  20,  50, 101,  30], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be the below code. But it's a really inefficient and inelegant one-liner.

```
df1.groupby('customer').apply(lambda x: (x['spend'].cumsum() *(x['spend'].cumsum() > x['hurdle']).astype(int).shift(-1)).fillna(x['spend']))
```

Comment: I've added an improved version on yours.